# How to get form fields in Xamarin Forms from button click

Tags: c#, mobile, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to grab the field values in the view in an MVVM setup with a button click using the ICommand interface. The end goal is to grab those fields in a button click to then save those fields into an SQLite DB. I'm providing the view, code-behind, and ViewModel which has the same fields as the model, to give a full picture, because I'm looking for how they all fit together and can't find a good example anywhere. Lots of links leading back to the MSDN page about making a clock, but that's not helping much with a form submit the type of task.

**Here is the view:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TermManager.Views.AddCourseView">
   <ContentPage.Content>
     <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Add Course" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" IsVisible="true" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="DarkBlue" Margin="10" />
            <Entry x:Name="CourseTitle" Placeholder="Course Title" Margin="3" />
            <Label Margin="3">Start Date</Label>
            <DatePicker x:Name="CourseStartDate" Margin="3" />
            <Label Margin="3">End Date</Label>
            <DatePicker x:Name="CourseEndDate" Margin="3" />
            <Picker x:Name="CourseStatus" Title="Course Status" Margin="3" TitleColor="DarkBlue">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>in progress</x:String>
                        <x:String>completed</x:String>
                        <x:String>dropped</x:String>
                        <x:String>plan to take</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
            <Entry x:Name="ProfessorName" Placeholder="Professor's Name" />
            <Entry x:Name="ProfessorPhone" Placeholder="Professor's Phone" />
            <Entry x:Name="ProfessorEmail" Placeholder="Professor's Email" />
            <Button x:Name="SaveCourseButton" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Text="Save" BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" TextColor="White" Margin="3" />
            <Button Text="Cancel" BackgroundColor="DarkRed" TextColor="White" Margin="3" Clicked="CancelCourseAddition" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using TermManager.Models;
using TermManager.ViewModels;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TermManager.Views
{
public partial class AddCourseView : ContentPage
{
    public int TermId { get; set; }

    private AddCourseViewModel viewModel = new AddCourseViewModel();

    public AddCourseView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    protected async void CancelCourseAddition(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }

    async void SaveButtonClicked(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var vm = sender as AddCourseViewModel;

        Course course = new Course
        {
            CourseStatus = vm.CourseStatus,
            CourseTitle = vm.CourseTitle,
            StartCourseDate = vm.StartCourseDate,
            EndCourseDate = vm.EndCourseDate,
            ProfessorEmail = vm.ProfessorEmail,
            ProfessorName = vm.ProfessorName,
            ProfessorPhone = vm.ProfessorPhone,
            TermId = vm.TermId
        };

        //viewModel.SaveNewTerm(course);
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
}
```

**View Model:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using TermManager.Models;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TermManager.ViewModels
{
    public class AddCourseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public int TermId { get; set; }
        public string CourseTitle { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartCourseDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndCourseDate { get; set; }
        public string CourseStatus { get; set; }
        public string ProfessorName { get; set; }
        public string ProfessorEmail { get; set; }
        public string ProfessorPhone { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public ICommand SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command((e) =>
                {
                    var item = (e as Course);

                    var test = item.CourseTitle;
                });
            }
        }

        public AddCourseViewModel()
        {
        }

        //public async void SaveNewTerm(Course course)
        //{
        //    await App.Database.SaveCourseAsync(course);
        //}
    }
}
```

Any help, advice, or tips with how to correctly implement grabbing those fields without using `x:Name="FieldName"` to populate a model would be really appreciated.

Comment: You missed one of the most important parts of MVVM: Binding. Inside the XAML you bind controls to properties of the ViewModel. There are lots of tutorials and HowTos for Binding with Xamarin. Read some of them

Comment: I'll look more into biding, thank you. Can you suggest any tutorials with in depth explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking is the `Binding` which if fact you are already using it with the `Command` and the `Button` click event.

The same way you can Bind properties from the ViewModel to the View into specific properties of the controls.

For example let's take one of your `Entry`'s:

```
<Entry x:Name="CourseTitle" 
    Text="{Binding CourseTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Placeholder="Course Title" 
    Margin="3" />
```

With the Text Property of the Entry we are telling to Bind the Value of the `CourseTitle` from the ViewModel.

You can read more about Databinding [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics)

But for the above to work you will need to add an extra step. Your ViewModel already implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` but your properties must notify when it has occurred a change in its value.

Something like this:

```
public string _courseTitle;
public string CourseTitle
{
    get => _courseTitle;
    set
    {
        _courseTitle = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CourseTitle));
    }
}
```

You will do this to all the other properties you want to bind to the UI and notify you about the changes.

And add this method:

```
    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

More about MVVM in Xamarin [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm)

Now you just need to add the same to the rest of your Controls in your UI matching your ViewModel Properties.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="TermManager.Views.AddCourseView">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Add Course" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" IsVisible="true" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="DarkBlue" Margin="10" />
            <Entry x:Name="CourseTitle" Text="{Binding CourseTitle, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Course Title" Margin="3" />
            <Label Margin="3">Start Date</Label>
            <DatePicker x:Name="CourseStartDate" Margin="3" />
            <Label Margin="3">End Date</Label>
            <DatePicker x:Name="CourseEndDate" Margin="3" />
            <Picker x:Name="CourseStatus" Title="Course Status" Margin="3" TitleColor="DarkBlue">
                <Picker.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                        <x:String>in progress</x:String>
                        <x:String>completed</x:String>
                        <x:String>dropped</x:String>
                        <x:String>plan to take</x:String>
                    </x:Array>
                </Picker.ItemsSource>
            </Picker>
            <Entry x:Name="ProfessorName" Text="{Binding ProfessorName, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Professor's Name" />
            <Entry x:Name="ProfessorPhone" Text="{Binding ProfessorPhone, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Professor's Phone" />
            <Entry x:Name="ProfessorEmail" Text="{Binding ProfessorEmail, Mode=TwoWay}" Placeholder="Professor's Email" />
            <Button x:Name="SaveCourseButton" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Text="Save" BackgroundColor="DarkBlue" TextColor="White" Margin="3" />
            <Button Text="Cancel" BackgroundColor="DarkRed" TextColor="White" Margin="3" Clicked="CancelCourseAddition" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Big Note:

With this, you will no longer need to set the values manually as you were doing it in the code behind. Just set the value to the values to your Properties in your ViewModel and they will populate your View.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: That certainly helps explain things better, thank you.